# Using javascript to handle breakpoints instead of css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Is it ok to handle breakpoints with javascript conditionally instead of css media queries? I have a react app which will show three different pages based on `window.innerWidth`. The thing is, based on different viewports, the elements hierarchy of the page will completely change. Hence i couldn't come up with a css idea and so i need to have three different return values and show them based on screen size. Anyway, is it a bad idea to handle all breakpoints with javascript instead of CSS(I mean not only in this case, but everywhere. Even when the hierarchy of elements stay the same)? Does it have performance issues, etc.?
Here's an example code:

```
export default function Example (props) {
    .
    .
    .
    useEffect(() => {
        window.onresize = breakpointHandler
    })

    const breakpointHandler = () => {
        const width = window.innerWidth
        if (width <= 860) {
            setSize('mobile')
        } else if (width > 860 && width <= 1400) {
            setSize('tablet')
        } else {
            setSize('desktop')
        }
    }

    if (size === 'mobile') {
        return (
            //mobile view
        )
    } else if (size === 'tablet') {
        return (
            //tablet view
        )
    } else if (size === 'desktop') {
        return (
            //desktop view
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Look for matchmedia in javascript and see if that is what you want.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's ok to handle things with JavaScript, if you can't handle them with only CSS. That's what JavaScript was introduced for. However, I'd suggest a few improvements of your code:

1. Use [debounce](https://javascript.info/task/debounce) or [throttle](https://javascript.info/task/throttle) for performance optimization. You're now executing code on every `onresize` event which is triggered on every pixel of screen size change and could result in performance issues.
2. Create custom hook `useViewChange` to encapsulate the logic of handling screen size change and reuse it in different components.
3. If you have several components that depend on window size, store current view type (mobile/tablet/desktop) in Rect context, for example. Then you will be calculating screen size only in AppComponent, store it in the context, while other components will just grab the value from context.
4. [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) can be really helpful

Comment: Thanks for the response. matchMedia is exactly what i've been looking for. I can bind eventListener to it aswell. Custom hook is a good idea too. And i didn't know about debounce and throttle. Thanks :D